# Response code 401 returned when trying to post tweet on twitter via Javascript

Tags: javascript, twitter

Hi I'm looking for some help please posting tweets to twitter from my website using javascript and the Twitter API.

I've created a small test react app which enables a user to write some text, attach an image and select a schedule (date and time) to post a tweet to my timeline on twitter. However when I click the post button I get a **401** error in the console. I've tried to post the tweet using both axios and an npm package I found 'oauth' but no luck with either.

Below are the two functions I wrote to test posting the tweet. Any help would be most appreciated.

**Axios Call**

```
const getTweetsAxios = () => {
    const url =
      "https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/users?usernames=MyTwitterUserName&format=detailed";
    const config = {
      accept: "*/*",
      authorization:
        "Bearer " + MyBearerToken,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "https://localhost:3000",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
    };

    axios
      .get(url, config)
      .then(response => {
        console.log("response: ", response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("error: ", error);
      });
  };
```

**OAuth Call**

```
const getTweetsOAuth = () => {
    const credentials = {
      consumer_key: "My Consumer Key Here",
      consumer_secret: "My Consumer Secret Here",
      access_token: "My Access Token Here",
      access_token_secret: "My Secret Token Here"
    };

    const oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token",
      "https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token",
      credentials.consumer_key,
      credentials.consumer_secret,
      "1.0A",
      null,
      "HMAC-SHA1"
    );

    oauth.get(
      "https://api.twitter.com/labs/1/users",
      credentials.access_token,
      credentials.access_token_secret,
      function(e, data, results) {
        console.log("e: ", e);
        console.log("data: ", data);
        console.log("results: ", results);
      }
    );
  };
```

Comment: I cannot see a call in your code here to POST a new Tweet; only calls to retrieve a user object. Also, the Twitter API does not support CORS, so this will not work from client-side Javascript.

Comment: The call is proxied to twitter so CORS is not an issue from the browser. I'm starting with a retrieval of data first to prove it can work before I add posting calls.